# how to control multiple JComboBoxes in java?

Tags: java, combobox, actionlistener

I have trouble with setting up 12 comboboxes on a JDialog. The first 4 are the gender of 4 individuals. The second 4 are their personality types. The third 4 are their job titles.

[image: CrewEditor]

How come when I change the 1st person's gender combobox, the 2nd, 3rd, 4th gender comboboxes are all being changed at the same time?

Why are they "linked" together? I already have separate ActionListeners for each?

The same thing with the personality comboboxes and the job comboboxes.

See attached pic.

What do I need to do to severe whatever linking them?

Also, Eclipse forces me to use "final" keyword on my customized JComboBoxMW.

Note that JComboBoxMW is nothing fancy. just extending the JComboBox class with better mouse wheel control.

See a portion of code below:

```
   public void setUpCrewGender() {

    List<String> genderList = new ArrayList<String>(2);
    genderList.add("M");
    genderList.add("F");
    genderComboBoxModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
    Iterator<String> i = genderList.iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        String s = i.next();
        genderComboBoxModel.addElement(s);
    }



    final JComboBoxMW<String> g1 = new JComboBoxMW<String>(genderComboBoxModel);
    g1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1) {
            String s1 = (String) g1.getSelectedItem();
            g1.setSelectedItem(s1);
        }});  
    g1.setMaximumRowCount(2);
    listPane.add(g1);


    final JComboBoxMW<String> g2 = new JComboBoxMW<String>(genderComboBoxModel);
    g2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e2) {
            String s2 = (String) g2.getSelectedItem();
            g2.setSelectedItem(s2);
        }});  
    g2.setMaximumRowCount(2);   
    listPane.add(g2);       

    final JComboBoxMW<String> g3 = new JComboBoxMW<String>(genderComboBoxModel);
    g3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e3) {
            String s3 = (String) g3.getSelectedItem();
            g3.setSelectedItem(s3);
        }});  
    g3.setMaximumRowCount(2);
    listPane.add(g3);



    final JComboBoxMW<String> g4 = new JComboBoxMW<String>(genderComboBoxModel);
    g4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e4) {
            String s4 = (String) g4.getSelectedItem();
            g4.setSelectedItem(s4);
        }});  
    g4.setMaximumRowCount(2);
    listPane.add(g4);

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the JComboBoxes share the same model, i.e., `genderComboBoxModel`, and thus will all the views will show the same model-state. Solution: give them unique models.

As an aside, consider using a JTable with JComboBox editors for your data entry.

Comment: I don't want to recreate the same model 4 times for selecting gender.  why is JComboBoxMW<String> g4 = new JComboBoxMW<String>(genderComboBoxModel) still not enough?

Comment: @mk7: if you want to fix your problem, then yeah, you do need to and *want* to create 4 models. Really, there's nothing that difficult about doing it, and it may add only 4 more lines of code to your program. If you don't believe me, believe MadProgrammer, one of the smartest Swing coder's I know. Also, it isn't a coincidence that we both gave you the same advice simultaneously, since we both saw the same glaring error simultaneously.

Comment: I'm using just a GridLayout within a BorderLayout. If I convert it to using JTable, will it simplify the code a bit?

Comment: @mk7: possibly. I do know that your current code has a **lot** of repetition. Why not create your combo's in a for loop, creating a new model each time? This way only one line of code creates the model, but it is repeated inside of the for loop.

Comment: @mk7: If you did decide to use a JTable, it would be best to transpose the display matrix, making each **row** represent one person rather than each column.

Comment: Sure. I just created a method for generating a new comboBox model and call that method each time before putting together a combobox for each person. It works. Thanks much!

Comment: So I created a setComboBoxModel() method to return a new comboBoxModel each time and it works. e.g. DefaultComboBoxModel<String> m1 = setComboBoxModel() ; How do I avoid the repetition further? I still have to have a separate Actionlistener for each comboBox in java, right?

Comment: @mk7: ActionListeners can be added inside of a method as well. Or it all can be a single class.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the same `ComboBoxModel` for each `JComboBox`, but the `ComboBoxModel` also manages the selected item, so when one combo box updates, all the other combo boxes are updated.

You need to create a separate/individual`ComboBoxModel` for each combo box which contains that data you want displayed instead

Comment: I thought I create a brand new copy by doing this: final JComboBoxMW<String> g4 = new JComboBoxMW<String>(genderComboBoxModel);

Comment: I didn't want the keyword final but it was forced upon me by Eclipse.

Comment: No, you're creating a new instance of `JComboBox`, but the model is the same, so whenever one combo box selects a value, all the combo boxes get notified and update themselves...